# Type 'PlayerConfiguration' has no member 'fromJson' Bitmovin iOS integration error

Tags: ios, swift, bitmovin-player

I'm trying to integrate Bitmovin ios. But when I Instantiate the Player through "let config = PlayerConfiguration.fromJson("");" method there show an error "Type 'PlayerConfiguration' has no member 'fromJson'". Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I found a solution.

I added following callbacks.

- fpsConfig.prepareCertificate
- fpsConfig.prepareLicense
- fpsConfig.prepareContentId
- fpsConfig.prepareMessage
  *
- Custom request headers can be set using:
- fpsConfig.certificateRequestHeaders
- fpsConfig.licenseRequestHeaders

  ```
  do { 
      try config.setSourceItem(url: fairplayStreamUrl)

      // create drm configuration
      let fpsConfig = FairplayConfiguration(license: licenseUrl, certificateURL: certificateUrl)

      // Example of how certificate data can be prepared if custom modifications are needed
      fpsConfig.prepareCertificate = { (data: Data) -> Data in
          // Do something with the loaded certificate
          return data
      }

      fpsConfig.prepareMessage = { (spcData: Data, assetID: String) -> Data in
          return spcData
      }

      fpsConfig.licenseRequestHeaders = ["content-type": "application/octet-stream"]

      fpsConfig.prepareLicense = { (ckc: Data) -> Data in
          return ckc
      }

      fpsConfig.prepareContentId = { (contentId: String) -> String in
          let part1 = contentId.components(separatedBy: ";")[1]
          let part2 = part1.components(separatedBy: "?")[0]
          return part2
      }

      config.sourceItem?.add(drmConfiguration: fpsConfig)

      // Create player based on player configuration
      let player = BitmovinPlayer(configuration: config)

      // Create player view and pass the player instance to it
      let playerView = BMPBitmovinPlayerView(player: player, frame: .zero)

      // Listen to player events
      player.add(listener: self)

      playerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
      playerView.frame = view.bounds

      view.addSubview(playerView)
      view.bringSubview(toFront: playerView)

      self.player = player
  } catch {
      print("Configuration error: \(error)")
  }
  ```